# 2 passwords in grub with 1 encrypted partition

Tags: grub2, luks, manjaro

I recently installed Manjaro Linux to my laptop with encrypted root. Almost everything is the same like on my desktop, but when I turn it on, I have to enter the password twice. Once before selection of os and once after that. Is there a way to get rid of the second one?

Comment: The first one is to decrypt, the second to login?

Comment: No, I will post pictures when I get home. First is before os selection, second after and third from the os, but that's not the problem.

Comment: Do you get such a password before entering BIOS? If so, it could be a FW password

Comment: No, it is not, I have a unique password for my encrypted partition.